# Is there a way to execute a method which is under a Button Click?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use Flutter. I have a method inside a button click event which executes.
I want to execute that method as soon as the dart screen opens just once. I cannot put the method inside the widget build as it would execute everytime the state is refreshed. Is there a way to execute button click event without the user actualy clicking on the button?

EDIT : I’m aware that I can use a boolean or some variable and set it to false after executing once. I was just looking for a way around that.

Comment: Hi, you can use a StateFullWidget and call your method in it's 'initState' method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call it in the `initState` method, like this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    yourMethodOnClick();
    super.initState();
  }
```

This is in case you are using it `StatefulWidget`

Either you use `StatelessWidget` You should call the method in the contractor, like this:

```
YourClass extends StatelessWidget{

    YourClass() {
       yourMethodOnClick();
    }

}
```

Comment: Trying to Execute
  @override
  void initState() {
    final provider = context.read<CalculateLength>();
    provider.getTemp(context: context, buttonText: '0');
    super.initState();
  }
It shows an error saying it canot be referenced from the build widget. Any other option?

Comment: You are welcome, I advise you next time to search carefully before you ask in Stackoverflow so that you do not rely on it too much, especially if you are a beginner, and I advise you to refer to the documentation in such questions